# Fasted way to increment a persistent counter from a node.js app?

Tags: node.js, persistence, redis

I have a search engine written in node.js/express that is currently not logging any statistics, and I'd like to start keeping track of # of queries per day. So I just need a persistent counter that I can increment each time a query is submitted. (I'll write a cron job to store it and clear it out at the end of the day, that's not relevant to this question).

There are obviously many ways to do this, so my one requirement is that it be very fast. Is redis overkill for this? Is there a simpler solution that would still be very fast?

Comment: There's no data persistence at all currently.

Comment: Than use fs. You mentioned a cron, so you meant to store results somewhere - so you do use some DB apparently.

Comment: I do not have any database yet. It's a simple app that just does redirection so far. Would the FS be faster than something like memcache?

Comment: No, I don't think fs will be faster as you have physical disc IO. Plus you'd need to write more logic for it, and with Memcache it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: my vote goes out to redis. Fast and persistent!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Literally fastest solution is using Memcache.

Create a counter object which has counters for each query, e.g.

```
counter = {
  '_q:whatever': 1,
  '_q:something else': 123
}
```

Then on page load add or increment keys in Counter. And then using cron pull Counter and parse all keys, update in your DB.